# PHP - Is it possible to upload a zip file to the database after the zip is created in php?

Tags: php

So, I watched a tutorial from a youtube video [here](http://tubeunblock.net/watch?v=uSOkmXtEHFQ) how to zip a file using php. This is the code I copied.

This is the form to upload zip. I choose 7 files and then name the archive name "testing".

[image: zip file]

After I clicked the "Add Files to Zip", the files are zipped and are sent to the directory.

[image: zip file 2]

These are the code

HTML Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Zip Archiving Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Archive Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br />
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="true">
<input type="submit" name="create" value="Create Zip"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload to Database">

</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['create']))
{
$filesArray = $_FILES["files"];

for($num = 0; $num < count($filesArray["name"]); $num++)
{
    $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
    $tempName = $filesArray["tmp_name"][$num];

    move_uploaded_file($tempName,"tmp/".$fileName);
}

$archiveName = $_POST['name'].".zip";
$filesArrayNames = $_FILES["files"]["name"];

$zipsDir = scandir("zips/");
$error = false;
foreach($zipsDir as $zipDirFile)
{
    if($zipDirFile == $archiveName)
    {
        $error = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($error == false)
{
    $tmpDir = scandir("tmp/");
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open("zips/".$archiveName, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    for($num = 0; $num < count($filesArray["name"]); $num++)
    {
        $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
        foreach($tmpDir as $tmpDirFile)
        {
            if($tmpDirFile == $fileName)
            {
                $zip->addFile("tmp/".$fileName);
                echo "Adding: ".$fileName."<br />";
            }
        }
    }
    $zip->close();

    for($num = 0; $num < count($filesArray["name"]); $num++)
    {
        $fileName = $filesArray["name"][$num];
        foreach($tmpDir as $tmpDirFile)
        {
            if($tmpDirFile == $fileName)
            {
                unlink("tmp/".$fileName);
            }
        }
    }
}


else
{
    echo "Name already exists";
}
}

if (isset($_POST['upload']))
{
    //code to add for uploading zip file to database

}

?>
```

But is it possible to upload the zip file after it is the files is zipped through php? I want the user to upload the files after the files are zipped.

Comment: You say `I want the user to upload the files after the files are zipped.` but if there are no files uploaded there is nothing you can .zip

Comment: you can insert files to a DB as a binary format and you can upload files to another server via `curl` or pure HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PHP` does not work on the user machine(the client) but in the server, so if you want to zip and then upload files think of scripts that run in the client side like `javascript`(`angularjs`, `jquery` and other libraries you can use) to use to zip you file and php  to accept them into the server.